# How to do make html foreach table?

Tags: php, html, css, html-table

I tried to do it but the big problem is foreach here i have the foto:
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQh0C.jpg)

[Here is my table picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETqcY.jpg)

Here is the code but still have problem:

```
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight">
            <tbody>
            <tr height="100">
                <td rowspan="6"  height="120" width="3%" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                    <p style="white-space: nowrap;writing-mode: vertical-lr;transform: rotate(180deg);font-weight: bold;"><font >Here is my title </font></p>
                </td>
                <td   colspan="3">
                <font>Name</font>
                </td>
                <td   width="64">
                <font>Article</font>
                </td>
                <td  width="64">
                <font>Price</font>
                </td>
                <td   width="64">
                <font>Date</font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="20">
                <td colspan="3" rowspan="5" height="120" ></td>
                <td rowspan="5" style="vertical-align: top;"></td>
                <td rowspan="5" style="vertical-align: top;"></td>
                <td rowspan="5" style="vertical-align: top;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="15">
            </tr>
            <tr height="15">
            </tr>
            <tr height="15">
            </tr>
            <tr height="15">
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

How can i do it so that when i use foreach it will insert new td and the vertical Here is my title will be there?

Comment: server side ( which language ) ? or client side ? where is the data you want to insert with the `foreach` ?

Comment: @Taki  sorry i forgot it. Is php and data comes from database into this tables.

Comment: Just wanted to say that there is a tag [`<th>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp) for the table header. It is placed before `<tbody>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, so you're using `php` here's a very basic example on how you can do that, i'm assuming you already did `query` and the fetching part, and this is a guess of your data structure, you can adjust it to your liking :

```
<div class="row">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight">
        <tbody>
        <tr height="100">
            <td rowspan="100%"  height="120" width="3%" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <p style="white-space: nowrap;writing-mode: vertical-lr;transform: rotate(180deg);font-weight: bold;"><font >Here is my title </font></p>
            </td>
            <td   colspan="3">
            <font>Name</font>
            </td>
            <td   width="64">
            <font>Article</font>
            </td>
            <td  width="64">
            <font>Price</font>
            </td>
            <td   width="64">
            <font>Date</font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            foreach($data as $key => $value){
                echo '<tr height="20">';
                    echo '<td colspan="3">'.$value['name'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td width="64" style="vertical-align: top;">'.$value['article'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td width="64" style="vertical-align: top;">'.$value['price'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td width="64" style="vertical-align: top;">'.$value['date'].'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kkpjx328/

I hope this helps .

**PS :** on your next question, please consider adding the data structure and if possible, an example or code sample of what you've tried so far so we can provide more specific answers

Comment: can you post a screenshot of that ?

Comment: oh, that's another problem, i just edited my answer to fit your case, check it out ( here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kkpjx328/ )

Comment: try to give there more then 6 td and you will see the error, i need that td with rowspan="6" will change everytime when i have more then look at that whrn you have jost one td like : https://jsfiddle.net/kkpjx328/2/ and   here : [https://jsfiddle.net/kkpjx328/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/kkpjx328/4/)

Comment: you can solve that by putting `rowspan="100%"`  on the first `<tr>` ( the one that has `rowspan="6"` - https://jsfiddle.net/kkpjx328/7/

Comment: thx for help but the problem is not solved : https://jsfiddle.net/kkpjx328/12/  and if i 't have any date in table its look like : https://jsfiddle.net/kkpjx328/15/ . Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: it's ok but it think we're getting way off topic here, you should mark the answer as accepted because it answers you question : `How to do make html foreach table?` which is about displaying the data in a `foreach` , and ask another question describing your current display problem with more details and i'll be glad to answer , however, the first fiddle in your last comment seems right to me and for the second one  i'm not sure i can understand what you mean, it would be really helpful if you describe that in another post, good luck.